# component builder with PHP or Nodejs

Tags: javascript, modularity

How does jquery.ui or modernizr generate code on the fly after you select which modules you need to include? 
Is it grunt with plugins like this https://npmjs.org/package/assemble or nodejs or PHP  ?
I've read jquery.ui switched to node for their download builder. I want to build something similar.

I have html template and need different css colors or javascript components every time user generates a template. So, form with checkboxes os perfect in my case, just like jqueryui or modernizr.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how they do it?  Or how you should do it?

Comment: In that case, can you elaborate a bit on your needs?

Comment: yes, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the core team for [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble), and first and foremost Assemble is just another Grunt.js plugin, we're just trying to make it easy to build components and sites by leveraging Grunt - since it is such an amazing build system.

The reason we created Assemble is for a similar use case to what you're describing. As programmers we always read about best practices of keeping data, structure, styles and so on separate.  In theory, this sounds great, but in reality we couldn't find any tools to help us achieve maintain code this way.

We did find tools that we admire, like YUI and jQuery UI, both of which offer powerful and interesting ways to work with modular, reusable code. But we decided to build Assemble because we wanted the flexibility to use whatever templating framework or data format was required for the job at hand.

So here is how you might build an example UI component with Assemble:

- The component will be a simple Bootstrap alert
- Templating language is Handlebars
- Data format is JSON, but we could alternatively use YAML or YAML Front-matter
- The variables I'm using in the example are arbitrary, make them whatever you want

Template: `alert.hbs`

```
<div class="alert {{ alert.modifier }}">
  <strong> {{ alert.strong }} </strong> {{ alert.message }} 
</div>
```

Data: `alert.json`

```
{
  "strong": "This is an alert",
  "modifier": "alert-info",
  "message": "This alert was assembled from a Handlebars partial and JSON data"
}
```

In the actual `assemble` task, there are a few ways you can build the templates, but let's say you want to build a bunch of components just like the alert into individual pages for documentation:

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  assemble: {
    options: {
      // built-in variable for resolving relative path to specified folder
      assets: 'dist/assets',
      // "layout" to wrap pages with header and/or footer
      layout: 'src/layouts/default.hbs',
      data: 'src/data/*.{json,yml}'
    },
    pages: {
      files: {
        // This is where "pages" are usually defined, but here we're pointing 
        // to the partials folder to build them into pages for documentation.
        'dist/': ['src/partials/*.hbs'],
      }        
    }
  }
});
```

Going further, you could easily add variable to the JSON file, or to YAML front matter in the partial to specify the stylesheet to use for the component.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely give it a try.